# Cannot install OpenCV for Python3 with APT

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, apt

I would like to install the package `python3-opencv` with *apt* on a Linux distribution. Installation is successful (no errors) but the package cannot be used from Python3.

Here is what I tried:
On Ubuntu 18.04 as well as on Debian Bullseye I installed it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

The installation succeeds without errors, but when I try to use it, it does not work:

```
$ python3 -c "import cv2 as cv"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I know i can install it via *pip* but I would like to use a pre-compiled package. Since there are packages provided in the repositories I would like to use them.

BUT HOW?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install the missing python module using `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not what I want. This results in building the whl. I would like to use the pre-built system installed package.